# SQL - query optimization to work with big data

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have table 33_PROBLEM with columns ROOT and ROOT_CUBED. Ten i have a simple procedure, that insert data, let´s begins with ROOT from -10000 to 10000, which means ROOT_CUBED from -10000^3 to 10000^3.

**Question is simple:**
How can I get all triplets combinations of ROOT_CUBED values, that add to number given?

**Said in different way:**
I want to find A, B, C for which is true, that A^3 + B^3 + C^3 = number_given

---

Here is some example for searched number 33:

```
SELECT T1.r1, 
       T2.r2, 
       T3.r3 
FROM   (SELECT root_3 AS R1 
        FROM   `33_problem`) AS T1, 
       (SELECT root_3 AS R2 
        FROM   `33_problem`) AS T2, 
       (SELECT root_3 AS R3 
        FROM   `33_problem`) AS T3 
WHERE  T1.r1 + T2.r2 + T3.r3 = 33
```

It works well ... on a small amount of rows. This query makes (COUNT *)^3 rows, which for 20000 input lines equals to 8e+12 rows !! ... RIP serever ...

---

what is the right way to solve this one?

---

( I got the idea from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wymmCdLdPvM and I hope, when someone comes with some answers, i will understand better, how SQL works and how queries and databases should be designed to work good even for big data )

Comment: I guess you mean column `root_3` instead of `root_cubed`

Answer (score 0):

1) you could try to only select sequential triplets, such that R1 <= R2 <= R3,

2) if you have duplicates, select distinct

```
SELECT T1.R1
  ,T2.R2
  ,T3.R3
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT ROOT_3 AS R1
  FROM `33_PROBLEM`
  ) AS T1
  ,(
    SELECT DISTINCT  ROOT_3 AS R2
    FROM `33_PROBLEM`
    WHERE R2>=R1
    ) AS T2
  ,(
    SELECT DISTINCT ROOT_3 AS R3
    FROM `33_PROBLEM`
    WHERE R3>=R2
    ) AS T3
WHERE T1.R1 + T2.R2 + T3.R3 = 33
```

Comment: Even when this reduce the `number of permutation / 6` when you have `8E+12` mean you still have `1.33E+12`

Comment: `R1 <= R2 <= R3` is not sufficient since the values can be negative.

Comment: Rick, not sure I follow regarding negative numbers. Negative numbers can be sequential too.

Answer (score 0):

I tried looking from -10000 to 10000 and there isn't a solution then i watched the youtube video and they say that they already tried up to 10 to the 14th and still no solution.

I did it with python code though when i tried -10000 to 10000...and to optimize of looking for the the C value.  First I look at the sum of A cubed and B cubed...the subtract that from 33 and calculate cube root the answer to try to find C in one hit... , this optimizes it a little because then you don't have to loop through all possible values of C.

Since there is no solution for up to 10 to 14th i don't think i can find a solution since just with -10000 to 10000 It took my computer over 2 hours to search. If i looked to 10 to the 14th it would takes like millions of years or something crazy.

Comment: At first I thought, SQL could be great tool for such a lookup.
I thought, i could use N rows and search them with linear memory use (X memory for program + N memory for rows). After some search, I didn´t find function for such a combination search, so I was forced to make posted select, which was much memory hungry (X + N^3 memory).

As I said, i don´t need a numeric answer, but rather hint, how to design and optimise tables and queries for such a task.

Answer (score 0):

You could work with a single table if integers, then do a "self join" using a "cross join".

For `R3`, you only need to check `-ROUND(POW(r1.root_3 + r2.root3, 1/3))`.  This should significantly speed things up.  Also, to make this work, be sure that you have a positive number.

```
SELECT t1.r1, t2.r2, -ROUND(POW(r1.root_3 + r2.root3, 1/3))
    FROM `33_PROBLEM` AS t1
    JOIN `33_PROBLEM` AS t2
    WHERE t1.root_3 > 0
      AND t2.root_3 > -t1.root_3
      AND (t1.root_3 + t2.root_3) = ROUND(POW(r1.root_3 + r2.root3, 1/3))
```